# How to create a location input bar in ios/Android?

Tags: android, ios, location

Looking for some clue to build a location input bar just above keyboard and user can tap location icon to input a location, similar as what Fb/twitter has on their mobile apps when click new post/tweet. 
Are there any existing library that support this? Should I create a customized keyboard with this bar? 
Many thanks for any clues!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are simply looking to create the bar above the keyboard, `inputAccessoryView`, a property of both UITextFields and UITextViews, is what you are looking for. This allows you to add a UIToolbar to the top of the keyboard similar to what both Twitter and Facebook do.

You can read further in the Apple documentation [here.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITextField/inputAccessoryView)

A simple implementation of this is as follows -

```
UIToolbar *locationToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];
locationToolbar.frame = CGRectMake(320, 384, 320, 53);
// Add location button to UIToolbar as desired
self.textField.inputAccessoryView = locationToolbar;
```

If you are looking to create a map to select the location from, [MKMapView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html) would be a good place to start.

Comment: Thanks a lot! How about in Android?

Comment: Sorry, I cannot help you with Android, I only have experience in Objective C. I was not sure which language you were looking for because you tagged both Android and iOS. I would imagine a search for "Android equivalent of UIToolbar" would show you what you need to know. You could then build upon that by seeing how you could add this toolbar to the top of the keyboard. I do not know if this is the best way to achieve the desired results in Android, but this does seam like the most logical way to approach this problem. Sorry I could not have been of more assistance on the Android side.